# Variable functions. Undefined function

Tags: php, function, variables

Could someone help me with dynamic functions?
I have

```
<?php
namespace app\components\Images;


function mobilePhone(){...}
function callFunctionForOrder($funcName)
{
    $funcName();
}
callFunctionForOrder('mobilePhone');
```

And get `Call to undefined function mobilePhone()`

But! 
If it looks like that

```
<?php
namespace app\components\Images;


function mobilePhone(){...}
function callFunctionForOrder($funcName)
{
    mobilePhone();
}
```

Then it works perfectly! What the hell? How can I fix that?

I'm doing so according to http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php

Comment: You're ignoring the fact that it's namespaced: `callFunctionForOrder(__NAMESPACE__ . '\\' . 'mobilePhone');`

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much! Post it like an answer so I could select it as the best one ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct your function like below

```
function callFunctionForOrder($funcName)
{
   call_user_func(__NAMESPACE__ .'\\'.$funcName );
}
```

For example

**Script**

```
akshay@db-3325:~$ cat test.php 
<?php
namespace app\components\Images;


function mobilePhone(){ echo 'mobile'.PHP_EOL; }
function callFunctionForOrder($funcName)
{
   call_user_func(__NAMESPACE__ . '\\'.$funcName );
}
callFunctionForOrder('mobilePhone');

?>
```

**Output**

```
akshay@db-3325:~$ php test.php 
mobile
```